# Instant comment deletion

Tags: support, comments, moderation

I am fully aware that comments are **temporary** means to communicate and improve a question or answer. Please don't mark this as a duplicate to the appropriate meta post, I have read all of them.

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51826/are-there-homebrew-fix-classes-or-rules-that-put-fighting-types-and-roguish-type) post of mine had 3 comments, some asking for clarification. I came back not an hour later to find them gone. The only answer I got was "take it to chat".

**I do not want to take it to chat!** What I want is *offline*, *non-realtime* communication with people. I don't even know most of them because voting is anonymous.

On what base is Brian Ballsun-Stanton deleting my completely appropriate comments after just minutes without letting me even know what was answered?

Who is he, to tell me that I *must have* an online chat? Does he someone own my PC or my network or my time using both?

Where can I challenge his decisions?

Comment: You may have a point, but your attitude isn't helping. In particular "Who is he" style rhetoric hurts your cause.

Comment: Yes, I'm pissed. As so often with this site. I cannot really say I'm sorry it shows. I'm not. I would not post this if I were happy.

Comment: As far as "Where can I challenge his decisions?" goes, the answer is here on Meta :) (Although I guess you already knew that.)

Answer (score 7):

The *12* deleted comments on that answer are in violation of site policy:

1. We forbid argument in comments. Chat is always logged, and voluntary, and so an isolated chat room is *less bad* than the alternative. Chat can absolutely be a semi-private voluntary asynchronous space for post improvement.
2. We forbid extended discussions in comments. There is a series of 5 answers in sequence that were intended to be a single super-length comment. That's not appropriate.
3. We allow answers to challenge the frame of the question. We do not allow play style discussions or arguments in comments (as per meta.)
4. The post has already been flagged multiple times, thus it has attracted moderator attention. The flags have been insufficiently persuasive to argue deletion.
5. If the option had been open to migrate the whole argument to a chat room, I would have taken it.

Back and forth discussion in comments is extremely discouraged. Back and forth arguments are nipped in the bud.

Comment: +1.  I understand that there are other factors in play here agitating you, but taken as a whole that comment thread needed to go away, as it was not very constructive and certainly very verbose. That's not all your fault, but that's the deal. Obviously you don't "have to" take it to chat, but as they say, "It's closing time - you don't have to go home, but you can't stay here."

Comment: Feature request: Move comments to chat??